# Material-UI React.js, Is there a way to have an onClick event for both a ListItem, and the ListItem's Avatar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material UI library, and cannot figure out if there is a way to have 2 different click events happening on a List Item.

This is basically what I have:

```
    <ListItem
      leftAvatar={
        <div onClick={() =>
          insideAvatarFunction()}
        >
          {<Avatar />}
        </div>
      }
      primaryText={primaryText}
      onTouchTap={() => everywhereClickFunction}
    />);
```

The onTouchTap triggers, and ignores the onClick inside of the leftAvatar. If the outer onTouchTap is not there, then the onClick triggers fine.

Is there a way to have the onTouchTap to trigger when anywhere BESIDES the avatar is clicked?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using stopPropagation() within the div's onClick anonymous function?

Comment: @zv.diego Thanks that worked! I am semi-new to web dev so I did not know about that. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

> Prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

```
import React from 'react';
import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  insideAvatarFunction(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Fired insideAvatarFunction()!');
  }

  everywhereClickFunction(e) {
    console.log('Fired everywhereClickFunction()!');
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <List>
        <ListItem primaryText="Inbox"
          leftAvatar={
            <div onClick={this.insideAvatarFunction}>
              <Avatar />
            </div>
          }
          onTouchTap={this.everywhereClickFunction}
          onClick={this.everywhereClickFunction}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

So when clicked on the Avatar's node, the `e.stopPropagation()` line in the  `insideAvatarFunction` should prevent the onClick/onTouchTap to further propagate to the parent's node which is the `ListItem` component.

Here is an interesting read about [Javascript Events Order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and event bubbling.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes across this question, the comment by @zv.diego solved the issue.

I put `stopPropagation()` inside the function of the div's `onClick`, and switched the parent to `onClick` instead of `onTouchTap` and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```html
You can use Avtar wrapped with IconButton.

import { IconButton, Avatar } from '@mui/material'

<IconButton 
   onClick={() => alert('Hiii')}>
     <Avatar
       src={userProfilePic(post.user)}
       sx={{ bgcolor: red[500] }}
       aria-label="recipe">
       post.user.firstName[0] + post.user.lastName[0]}
     </Avatar>
</IconButton>
```